# Replace variable name taking care of shadow variables

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm parsing a GLSL source code and I need to replace global variable name with a new name. The problem is how to take care of shadow variable? For example, in the following source code, I would like to replace lines `a = 1` and `a = 3` but not `a = 2` because of the local declaration.

```
int a; // To be replaced

void some_function(void)
{
    a = 1; // To be replaced
    {
         int a;
         a = 2; // To be kept
    }
    a = 3; // To be replaced
}
```

I'm using pyparsing but I did not find a solution (apart using `nestedExpr` and re-parsing each block).

Comment: "C-like source code?" so is this C or not? I just did this kind of stuff for javascript source 2 days ago (name mangling); you need to preferably make this into a proper abstract syntax tree and then visit the nodes noting all variables that are declared there, then calculating which of them are global etc.

Comment: This is GLSL code (corrected) but I don't want to go into a full parser. The goal is only to mangle names such as to be able to mix shader snippets together.

Comment: in that case it is safe to mangle *all* variables :D

Comment: You're right ! I need to test the idea but I do not see obvious problems. Thanks.